# Where is the source for the Built-In Display Templates in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

[Brad Wilson states](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) that "The default templates in ASP.NET MVC are done in code."  In that post, he recreates the functionality as ASCX files.  Where can the code for the actual default templates be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stated in the link you gave :

> The default templates in ASP.NET MVC
>   are done in code, but here I’ve
>   replaced their functionality as .ascx
>   files, to illustrate what they do (and
>   give you a starting point for
>   customizing your own versions of all
>   these templates).

So if you look through the [source of Asp.Net MVC2](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742) you'll find the implementation of those template in the `DefaultEditorTemplates` class and the `DefaultEditorTemplates` located in the Html folder